# Initialise autowired service in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am running 100 JUnit tests with a single autowired service. I have a service named createArray this service adds values in the ArrayList.
The problem is the values persist in the array list. When a new test case runs it adds its own value to the array.

I want to clear the autowired creatArray object whenever new test case runs.

Answer (score 0):

Spring beans by default are singleton, this is why this is happening.
In order to have a different behaviour you should check the different "bean scope".
This is a quick explanation of it:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_bean_scopes.htm

I believe that if you use the prototype scope ( as per this tutorial ) you might end up with the solution you want.

Regarding how to do this, it really depends if your beans are defined by xml or annotation.

You can check google a lot of examples.

In case you using XML it should be easy, on the bean add the `"scope=prototype"`.
For annotation use under `@Bean` the annotation `@Scope("prototype")`